# Dynamic cardviews combined with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, android-cardview

I'm having a list of `CardViews`. Each `CardView` (representing a challenge) has a `ViewPager` to show a vertical scrolable list of "solutions".

The data and images in the "solutions list" is coming from a `Firebase` database. 
**The issue that I have is that the first CardView you open** (when you click on it, it expands and shows the solutions) **displays all the solutions correctly. When you click on the second one, it expands but no data is shown and I think it is like this because I have to work with a "final" layout** ( `final FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions, null);`)

[image]

This below is a snippet of the important parts of the custom `RecyclerView` adapter.

```
public class ChallengesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ChallengesAdapter.RecyclerItemViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ChallengesData> myChallengesList;
int mLastPosition = 0;

//Firebase
String mUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference challengeSolutionsRef = rootRef.child("challenges");

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("firebase-url");

public ChallengesAdapter(ArrayList<ChallengesData> myChallengesList) {
    this.myChallengesList = myChallengesList;
}
public RecyclerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.challenges_row, parent, false);
    RecyclerItemViewHolder holder = new RecyclerItemViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.etTitleTextView.setText(myChallengesList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.etDescriptionTextView.setText(myChallengesList.get(position).getDescription());
    mLastPosition =position;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return(null != myChallengesList ? myChallengesList.size():0);
}
public void notifyData(ArrayList<ChallengesData> myList) {
    this.myChallengesList = myList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public class RecyclerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView etTitleTextView;
    private final TextView etDescriptionTextView;
    //private final TextView etContent;
    private final ChallengesPagerAdapter myChallengesPagerAdapter;
    private final ViewPager myViewPager;
    private final FrameLayout myFrameLayout;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

    public RecyclerItemViewHolder(final View parent) {
        super(parent);
        etTitleTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        etDescriptionTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        myChallengesPagerAdapter = new ChallengesPagerAdapter();
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myChallengesPagerAdapter);
        myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.framelayout_view_pager);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                challengeSolutionsRef = challengeSolutionsRef.child(myChallengesList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getChallengeKey()).child("solutions");
                challengeSolutionsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        DatabaseReference solutionsRef = rootRef.child("solutions").child(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        solutionsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                final FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions, null);
                                TextView TVSolutionID = (TextView)v0.findViewById(R.id.txtSolutionID);
                                TextView TVUserID = (TextView)v0.findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
                                TVSolutionID.setText(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                                String UserID = dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
                                TVUserID.setText(UserID);

                                myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                //get file from cloud
                                storageRef.child("solutions/").child(dataSnapshot.child("images").getValue(String.class) + ".jpg").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                        // Use the bytes to display the image
                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                        ImageView IVSolution = (ImageView)v0.findViewById(R.id.ivSolutionImage);
                                        IVSolution.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                        myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        ImageView IVSolution = (ImageView)v0.findViewById(R.id.ivSolutionImage);
                                        IVSolution.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_challenger_black);
                                        myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                                myChallengesPagerAdapter.addView(v0);
                                myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.d("Test","The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                            }

                        });
                    }

                        ....

                });

                ....
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**This is the challenges_row.xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_back"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/arrow_forward"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is solutions.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSolutionID"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUserID"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSolutionImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Edit with advise from Marcos: (still same result)**

```
public class ChallengesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChallengesAdapter.RecyclerItemViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ChallengesData> myChallengesList;
int mLastPosition = 0;

//Firebase
String mUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference challengeSolutionsRef = rootRef.child("challenges");

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("firebase-url");    

public ChallengesAdapter(ArrayList<ChallengesData> myChallengesList) {
    this.myChallengesList = myChallengesList;
}
public RecyclerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.challenges_row, parent, false);
    RecyclerItemViewHolder holder = new RecyclerItemViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.etTitleTextView.setText(myChallengesList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.etDescriptionTextView.setText(myChallengesList.get(position).getDescription());
    mLastPosition =position;

    holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Position:" + myChallengesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //create reference to solutions inside challenges data
            challengeSolutionsRef = challengeSolutionsRef.child(myChallengesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getChallengeKey()).child("solutions");
            challengeSolutionsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

                    DatabaseReference solutionsRef = rootRef.child("solutions").child(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    solutionsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            holder.v0 = (FrameLayout) holder.myInflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions, null);
                            TextView TVSolutionID = (TextView)holder.v0.findViewById(R.id.txtSolutionID);
                            TextView TVUserID = (TextView)holder.v0.findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
                            TVSolutionID.setText(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                            String UserID = dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
                            TVUserID.setText(UserID);

                            holder.myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            storageRef.child("Solutions/").child(dataSnapshot.child("picture").getValue("filename").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                    // Use the bytes to display the image
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                                    ImageView IVSolution = (ImageView)holder.v0.findViewById(R.id.ivSolutionImage);
                                    IVSolution.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                    holder.myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                    // Handle any errors
                                    //Create new item in the rowItems arraylist to add to the listview
                                    ImageView IVSolution = (ImageView)holder.v0.findViewById(R.id.ivSolutionImage);
                                    IVSolution.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_challenger_black);
                                    holder.myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                            holder.myChallengesPagerAdapter.addView(holder.v0);
                            holder.myChallengesPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d("Test","The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                        }

                    });
                }
 ...

            });

    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return(null != myChallengesList ? myChallengesList.size():0);
}
public void notifyData(ArrayList<ChallengesData> myList) {
    this.myChallengesList = myList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public class RecyclerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView etTitleTextView;
    private TextView etDescriptionTextView;
    //private final TextView etContent;
    private ChallengesPagerAdapter myChallengesPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private FrameLayout myFrameLayout;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private View myParent;
    private LayoutInflater myInflater;
    private FrameLayout v0;
    public RecyclerItemViewHolder(final View parent) {
        super(parent);
        etTitleTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        etDescriptionTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        myChallengesPagerAdapter = new ChallengesPagerAdapter();
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myChallengesPagerAdapter);
        myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.framelayout_view_pager);
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        myParent = parent;
        myInflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Change your addActionListeners that is at the ViwHolder creation to the onBindViewHolder

Comment: I've made the change you suggested but it doesn't seem to fix it. Can you have a look at the code at the bottom of the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of Marcus was not 100% clear to me but it got me thinking and made me understand the viewpager/adapter link better. I remove the cardview pard and I my a normal listview with a viewpager inside. This is a short version of the code (some parts are missing!).

In the fragment I made a list of a custom data class. Each part of the list represents 1 row. The  list is added to the custom adapter (code is below) and this custom adapter is added to the listview (mylistview).

**Fragment.java**

```
List<ChallengesData> rowItems;
ListView mylistview;


    @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_challenges_overview, container, false);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<ChallengesData>();

    final SolutionsAdapter adapter = new SolutionsAdapter(getContext(), rowItems);
    mylistview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LVChallenges);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) { 
            final String challengeKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            DatabaseReference groupKeyRef = rootRef.child(....).child(challengeKey);

            groupKeyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                    String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);

                    ChallengesData data = new ChallengesData(title,description,challengeKey);
                    int dataIndex = findDataitem(rowItems,challengeKey);
                    if(dataIndex == -1){
                        //group not yet added so add group
                        rowItems.add(data);
                    }
                    else{
                        rowItems.set(dataIndex,data);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }

              "here were other @override functions"
    };
    userChallengeRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    return rootView;
}
```

The listview inside the xml:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/LVChallenges"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

**SolutionsAdapter.xml**

In constructor, get the context so we can inflate on the correct place and get the items needed for the listview. Inflate the layout you want inside the viewpager, assign the values to the layout. Then create list for the viewpager items (myViewpagerlist), give the view (convertview) to the custom adapter (vpadapter) so it can inflate on the correct spot. Make a new viewpager, add the layout element to it and add the custom adapter (vpadapter) to it. Fill the list for the viewpager (myviewpagerlist) and call the notifyDataSetChanged() function.

```
    Context context;
List<ChallengesData> rowItems;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

SolutionsAdapter(Context context, List<ChallengesData> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView description;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    ChallengesData row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
    //LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {


        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(row_pos.getDescription());

    //List inside viewpager
    final ArrayList<SolutionsData> myViewPagerList = new ArrayList<SolutionsData>();
    final VPadapter myVPadapter = new VPadapter(convertView.getContext(),myViewPagerList);

    final ViewPager myViewPager;
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    myViewPager.setAdapter(myVPadapter);

    DatabaseReference challengeSolRef = rootRef.child("...."); 
    challengeSolRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            DatabaseReference SolutionRef = rootRef.child("..."); 
            SolutionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    final String solutionsKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    final String userID = dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class);
                    final String description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);

                    //get file from cloud
                    storageRef.child("....").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            // Use the bytes to display the image
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            SolutionsData solData = new SolutionsData(solutionsKey,userID,description,bytes);
                            int rowItemIndex = findSolutionIitem(myViewPagerList,solutionsKey);
                            if(rowItemIndex == -1){
                                //group not yet added so add group
                                myViewPagerList.add(solData);
                            }
                            else{
                                myViewPagerList.set(rowItemIndex,solData);
                            }
                            myVPadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {                                // Handle any errors
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**VPAdapter.java**
Create a new view, assign the correct data to it and done.

```
class VPadapter extends PagerAdapter{
// This holds all the currently displayable views, in order from left to right.
private ArrayList<SolutionsData> views;

Context context;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

VPadapter(Context context, ArrayList<SolutionsData> myViewPagerList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.views = myViewPagerList;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  "Object" represents the page; tell the ViewPager where the
// page should be displayed, from left-to-right.  If the page no longer exists,
// return POSITION_NONE.
@Override
public int getItemPosition (Object object)
{
    int index = views.indexOf (object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager needs a page to display; it is our job
// to add the page to the container, which is normally the ViewPager itself.  Since
// all our pages are persistent, we simply retrieve it from our "views" ArrayList.
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
{
    SolutionsData row_pos = views.get(position);

    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions,null);
    TextView SIDview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSolutionID);
    SIDview.setText(row_pos.getSolutionKey());
    Image.setImageBitmap(row_pos.getSolutionImageBitmap());
    container.addView (v);

    return v;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.  Called when ViewPager no longer needs a page to display; it
// is our job to remove the page from the container, which is normally the
// ViewPager itself.  Since all our pages are persistent, we do nothing to the
// contents of our "views" ArrayList.
@Override
public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    container.removeView ((View) object);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager; can be used by app as well.
// Returns the total number of pages that the ViewPage can display.  This must
// never be 0.
@Override
public int getCount ()
{
    return views.size();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Used by ViewPager.
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)
{
    return view == object;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you followed the solution, you need to fix this:

```
 holder.v0 = (FrameLayout) holder.myInflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions, null);
```

This statement is creating a view that is not attached to the ViewHolder, and the result will be empty.

In the ViewHolder constructor get the reference of the viewpager that is inside the viewholder (not the main one) and assign the a solutionsAdapter to it.

The SolutionsAdapter will hold a List of objects, that you will modify in the place of that line I pointed out.

The solutions adapter will provides instances of holder.myInflater.inflate(R.layout.solutions, null, false) on create view and set the values in onBindViewHolder.

Summary:

Your screen has a RecyclerView with one Adapter that returns a view (of Challenges) that has a ViewPager;
The item view (of Challenges) needs an Adapter to its ViewPager (of Solutions) that you can modify.

Comment: I understand that I have to create a 2th adapter (solutionsAdapter), but I don't see how I can "link" it: _"In the ViewHolder constructor get the reference of the viewpager that is inside the viewholder (not the main one) and assign the a solutionsAdapter to it."_ I already have an adapter assigned to the viewpager             `myViewPager = (ViewPager) parent.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            myViewPager.setAdapter(myChallengesPagerAdapter);` . Do I have to remove this one and set the solutionsAdapter? Or do I need 2 viewpagers?

Comment: Exactly, you may replace myChallengesPagerAdapter for a SolutionsAdapter

Comment: I'm struggling! Does the SolutionsAdapter also be a RecyclerView? I hope you could explain it a bit more detailed.

Comment: If you use ViewPager it must be a ViewPagerAdapter, if you use a RecyclerView use a RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: You get the bounty as your input made me rethink views and viewpagers.